# Fix openRedirect using ESAPI sendRedirect but not working in Java?

Tags: java, security, fortify, esapi

I am trying to fix open redirect issue reported in my Java code. The current code I have used is:
`response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestUrl().toString());`

I have used ESAPI but somehow is it not redirecting to the required servlet. I used ESAPI like below:

```
ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(req, resp);
ESAPI.httpUtilities().sendRedirect(location);
ESAPI.httpUtilities().clearCurrent();
```

Both ESAPI.properties and Validator.properties were uploaded successfully. I have also made changes in ESAPI.properties by replacing **test** with my application name like this:
`Validator.Redirect="^/<MyApplicationName>.*$ "`

Sample URL for my app is `https:\\localhost\<MyApplicationName>\com\sos\servlet\Login`

Can anyone let me know what am I missing or what wrong am I doing?

Comment: When you debug it, what is the value for `location`?

Comment: I get this URL in location - https:\\localhost\<ApplicationName>\servlet\com.sos.servlet.Login?SessionID=<EncryptedValue> where Login.java is servlet name